# Different file for different user

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a forum.

I already have the login and registration for it, but my problem now is, I don't have a single idea on how to create a different file for every different subject (thread) that users are going to create. My first look was at the `fopen()` function, but you can't add html and php when writing in the file `fwrite()` ... or could you?

So, I'm sure it can be done, but I really don't know how to do it. I have in mind what kind of database I should create for a threads and what kind of database I should create for comments and how to join them together (something like: `this thread has been created by: X`), but don't have an idea on how to create a different file for every subject.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you for reading. If you require any different details, I would gladly give them to you.

Comment: Just use a mysql database instead of using files

Comment: Before diving in and writing your own forum software, you should take a look at some of the many open source examples that are available. You may find one that'll work for what you want to do, and therefore save you a lot of work. Either way, you'll certainly learn quite a bit about how other people have solved the same problem in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing all the data in flat files probably isn't the best approach. As you have more people using the forum, you will run into issues with file-locking and what not.

You can store your data in various databases. Most commonly, data is stored in a relational database such as MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL and numerous others. My suggestion would be to try and play around with a few of these to see what you prefer.

On the other hand, there are also NoSQL solutions (sometimes called document stores). Some of these are: MongoDB, couchDB and simpleDB. These are not relational, but I believe that can still work well when applied to forums.

As for structuring your code, you can do the following:

- A file called `thread.php`. To request a thread you can do: `http://site.com/thread.php/1234/my-awesome-thread`, where `1234` is a unique ID for each thread.
- `post.php` where a user gets a form to submit a new post or a reply to an existing thread.

Having said that, this is probably the most straight forward way to code the application. However, it probably isn't the best way in terms of maintainability and code reuse. If the application is to grow and become very big, then investing time in building a MVC (model, view, controller) structure or using an existing MVC framework would probably save a lot of pain and headaches. :)

Comment: Right....http://site.com/thread.php/1234/my-awesome-thread.    I am not sure how you would do the /1234/my-awesome-tread. Please reply

Comment: @Bula, do you have _any_ sort of experience with web development? You should be able to work out what to do with 5 minutes or so of Googling .

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which will return `/thread.php/1234/my-awesome-thread`, it is then up to you to parse that string and extract what you need.